# How to apply @Language annotation for IntelliJ syntax highlighting on my own extension property

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, kotlin, syntax-highlighting

I am writing some regular-expression-heavy code, and I am finding that the usual syntax for using regular expressions in Kotlin, namely,

```
"""a.*b""".toRegex()
```

is a bit verbose and distracting for my taste. It occurred to me that I could shorten it considerably by creating an extension property on String, so that I could instead write such code as:

```
"""a.*b""".rx
```

At a syntactic level, I can easily write an extension function like this, which does the job:

```
val String.rx : Regex
    get() { return toRegex() }
```

However, when I use this, the string no longer gets displayed in IntelliJ Idea with syntax highlighting for a regular expression ("language injection"), as the original string that I called .toRegex() on did.

In similar circumstances elsewhere (e.g. strings passed as function parameters) I solved this problem by adding a '@Language("RegExp")' annotation to the function parameter in question, which gives IntelliJ enough information to know that any string passed into that parameter of the function should be a valid regular expression, and should be highlighted as such. However, I have not been able to figure out how to apply this annotation to this extension property to get this same highlighting behavior.

I first tried the obvious, trying putting the annotation in each possible location within the property, like this for instance:

```
@Language("RegExp")
val String.rx : Regex
    get() { return toRegex() }
```

or this:

```
val @Language("RegExp") String.rx : Regex
    get() { return toRegex() }
```

but the Kotlin compiler did not accept it.

I then looked at the Kotlin docs [here](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) which seemed to suggest that the proper syntax for annotating the receiver of the extension property might be something like this:

```
@get:Language("RegExp")
val @receiver:Language("RegExp") String.rx : Regex
    get() { return toRegex() }
```

This compiles, but has no effect on IntelliJ's syntax highlighting.

I also have not succeeded in declaring an ordinary extension function (as opposed to an extension property) to do what String.toRegex() does with regards to syntax highlighing.

Oddly, the String.toRegex() function itself has no relevant annotations, so I don't know how IntelliJ decides that it should highlight the receiver of the toRegex() call as a regular expression, or why it does not treat my own attempts at an extension function likewise.

Can this be done? If so, what is the proper syntax for declaring a annotation for an extension property and/or an extension function so that it will be seen by IntelliJ and will affect IntelliJ's syntax highlighting?

Comment: In light of the discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307248/putting-language-annotations-on-extension-method-receiver, I have filed the following issue on the Idea Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-205000

Comment: You may want to take a look at the Kotlin entry in `Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`.